# Getting an error with Jenssegers: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, drivers, jenssegers-mongodb

I'm using Laravel 5.4 with Valet. I've installed PHP 7.1 and MongoDB drivers for PHP. I've followed every instruction to setup my Laravel project with MongoDB but when I try to communicate with my DB I get this error:

> FatalThrowableError in Client.php line 81:
>   Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

I checked my extensions in my PHP.ini and it's all there. Everything is fine but my project won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need to run `composer install` to get your libraries installed (https://getcomposer.org/). If it fails after that, you may need the pecl mongodb library (at https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb).

Run a `php -m` to ensure that your mongo library is installed also. Just because it's in your php.ini does not mean it's shared libraries or other files are available.